# Is natural language logic agnostic?

Tags: logic, natural-language

Is natural language logic agnostic? By that, I mean are there rules in classical logic that is implied to be true by natural language, are there logic rules in classical logic that must be true in order for natural language to work as intended, or is natural language logic agnostic in that natural language will function no matter what logic we're subscribing to or what logic is true.

Comment: Logicians used to view logic as a replacement for natural language rather than a tool for analyzing it, [Montague grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montague_grammar) was invented to unify natural language with higher-order predicate and modal logics with hyperintensional λ-calculus: *my opinion no important difference between natural languages and the artificial languages of logicians... possible to comprehend the syntax and semantics of both kinds of language within a single natural and mathematically precise theory... I differ from a number of philosophers, but agree with Chomsky...*

Comment: Natural language is logic vague, a loose collection of language games related by family resemblance, as Wittgenstein put it. There are large fragments of it that follow certain rules of logic, which is why Aristotle was able to extract his syllogistic and Boole his algebra, but even that required idealization. Natural implication is systematically non-classical, not even truth functional. Connectives have context sensitive meanings, even identity and non-contradiction are flouted at times. But it is the case where any rule can be dropped but not all at once, or sense will be lost completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural language is indeed a loose collection of language games and those games do not necessarily follow the rules of classical logic. But classical logic is itself a language game amongst all the others - and it may be more accurate to think of it as also a collection of games.

However, classical logic is itself a language game, and just as its rules enable it to meet certain needs and desires of human beings, so all the other language games meet different needs and desires of human beings.

In the same way that classical logic has precise rules which cannot be broken without the risk of failing to communicate within the game, all other language games have rules that need to be kept if the game is to continue.

From the point of view of classical logic, many natural language games are vague. But they are often very precise in their way. J.L. Austin was brilliant at showing this, especially in his article "A Plea for Excuses".

However, it is true that the rules of a language game are very adaptable and capable of changing as the needs and desires of the players change and develop. So it should not be surprising that one can see the same process at work in logic.

Few philosophers now accept the view that classical logic is the standard by which natural language can be assessed and "regularized". I would go further and suggest that classical logic must, in the end, fit in (in some loose sense) with natural language. After all, if it didn't, no-one could ever learn it.